# GPU memory performance effects

Tags: memory, graphics-card, gpu

What performance effects should I expect by downgrading from 3GB to 1.5GB on the same video card (an nvidia GTX 560m if it matters). I have read that the extra memory over 1.5GB is mostly superfluous, but that was in 2011 [(1)](http://forum.notebookreview.com/gaming-software-graphics-cards/594719-nvidia-gtx-560m-1-5gb-vs-3gb.html), [(2)](http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/what-card-is-more-powerfull-gtx-560m-3gb-vs-geforce-gtx-485m.147375/). Apparently it has to do with screen resolution, and my screen is from 2011 also, if that matters. I want my laptop to be viable for playing games for as long as possible.

Comment: monitor the GPU memory usage with MSI Afterburner. If you never use more than 1.5GB you'll see no difference.

Comment: @magic unfortunately that is not possible right now, because my motherboard needs to be replaced (hence the question). I will keep it in mind for later though.

Comment: this is not possible to answer. We don't know what you use your GPU for.

Comment: @magic it serves my ASUS G74Sx laptop, which I use for playing modern games. I don't really care about multi-monitor performance, though it would be nice to know. However, I am also asking this question in more general terms. Ie, what factors would determine whether it would make a difference.

Comment: the card is too slow for gaming. use an eGPU (remove the Wifi card to get a Mini PCIe slot): http://forum.techinferno.com/diy-e-gpu-projects/2109-diy-egpu-experiences-%5Bversion-2-0%5D.html

Comment: ...I had one before and used it to play games all the time with no problem.

Comment: games get higher requirements and so you can upgrade the external one while the internal is fixed on the mainboard of the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

The textures applied to 3D objects are held in the graphics cards memory.  By reducing the memory, you reduce the amount and/or size of the the textures that can be loaded at one time.  With lower memory, you may have to wait for a texture to load and be rendered.

Also, lowering the graphics memory can reduce the amount of onscreen objects that can be drawn.  However, depending on the program, the number of objects could be the same, but performance will degrade.

Comment: What about all the people saying that the GTX 560m would never need 3GB of video ram? Is there any truth to that claim?

Comment: http://www.techhive.com/article/155984/worst_tech_predictions.html

Comment: That's not much of answer. And I don't think it was so much a prediction as an extrapolation from the parameters of the component.